# Android How to implement Inline auto-complete function for AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to do the AutoCompleteTextView Inline auto-completely. Just like google chrome url does. When you input some words, it will help to automatically complete the most recently url that user input, also can continue input the auto fill part, just like the below picture showed. I want to know how to do this in Android AutoCompleteTextView. It can auto fill the AutoCompleteTextView line and also can change what user was not input.

It is inline auto complete not just AutoCompleteTextView and drop down.

[image: google auto complete]

Comment: AutoCompletTextView?

Comment: How do you display multiple suggestions on one line? Use http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete instead

Comment: It not just AutoCompleteTextView, It need Inline auto complete..Understand the question clearly..